# Expected number of visits of a Markov Chain on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

Suppose I have a Markov Chain with state space $\mathbb{Z}$ with

$\mathbb{P}(X_n=X_{n-1}+1|X_{n-1})=\lambda$, $\mathbb{P}(X_n=X_{n-1}-1|X_{n-1})=\mu$

where $\lambda+\mu=1$, $\lambda,\mu>0$ and $\lambda\neq\mu$. How do I compute the expected number of visits to a state $n$?

Comment: What are the probabilities of the two states at the beginning and the end of the chain?

Comment: There are no ends, its on the whole of $\mathbb{Z}$. I should have said it starts at 0 but I don't think this matters since we visit every state with robability 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MC=Markov Chain.

Let $$f_{jj}=P( \text{MC visits(in finite time)  state}\;j \mid X_0=j).$$

Notice that given the Markov property once the MC visits state  $j$ either returns to this state with probability $f_{jj}$ or leaves it forever with probability $1-f_{jj}$. Let $A$ be this last event with  $P(A)=1-f_{jj}$.

Let $N_j$:=the number of visits of the  MC to  the state $j$= $\sum_ {n=1}^{\infty} 1 (X_n=j)$.

Then, $$P(N_j=k\mid X_0)=[1-P(A)]^{k-1}P(A)=f_{jj}^{k-1}(1-f_{jj})$$

This means that $$N_j\mid X_0 \sim \text{Geometric}(p=1-f_{jj})$$

The expected number of visits is $E(N_j\mid X_0)=\frac{1}{1-f_{jj}}$

This is finite when $f_{jj}<1$. A non-symmetric random walk  the chain abandons state $j$ with positive probability $1-f_{jj}$ so the expectation is finite.

In simple terms a  state  is recurrent when beginning at this state the chain  at some point   revisits it with probability 1.   A simple  random walk is recurrent only when $\mu=\lambda=1/2$

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I thought $f_{jj}$ was always one which was my error. What's wrong with the following: Suppose we let $B_n$ be the probability we hit state $i$ from initial state $n$ with $B_i=1$ (i.e. we count the initial state). We form a recurrence relation in the usual way and gain $B_n=a(1-(\frac{\mu}{\lambda})^{n-i})+(\frac{\mu}{\lambda})^{n-i}$. Now clearly $B_n$ is finite so we must have $a=1$. But then after conditioning on the first step once we have left $i$ we must have $f_{ii}=1$?

Comment: Hmm maybe I can't apply the reccurrence relation over $B_i$? But rather have matching conditions...

Comment: For the SRW $f_{00}=1-\mid \lambda-\mu\mid$. It clear that when $\mu=\lambda=1/2$  state $0$ is recurrent ie $f_{00}=1$ otherwise it is transient. However, even when we have recurrence the expected  time of return is $\infty$,  null persistent  ot null recurrent  state.

Comment: @theoGR, thanks I found this explanation very helpful.  Can you please explain to me the logic behind this line? $P(N_j=k\mid X_0)=[1-P(A)]^{k-1}P(A)=f_{jj}^{k-1}(1-f_{jj})$  It seems as if this geometric distribution follows from defining a Bernoulli trial.  I understand that $N_j$ is the random variable for the number of successes.  But what can we define as the number of trials in this case?  Isn't it $\infty$??  thanks again for helping me understand this better.